# sql statement incorrect syntax near '?'

Tags: sql, syntax

Hi I am moving my local database that used good old access to sql server. I am having trouble with my insert statement which says "incorrect syntax near '?'"

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tblStudent(studentID,studentFirstName,studentLastName,studentPrefName,addressO1,addressO2,addressO3,addressO4,phoneO,phoneAltO,address1,address2,address3,address4,phone,phoneAlt,guardianID,agentID,emailAddress,schoolID,status) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Comment: Moving to another SQL Server database?

Comment: Sql-Server uses named parameters, replace your question marks with the actual column names and prepend it with `@`, f.e.: `...VALUES (@studentID,@studentFirstName,@studentLastName...`. You have to use these placeholder when you use `... .Parameters.Add("@studentID", SqlDbType.Int).Value=studentId`

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: How are you executing "sql"?  Are you correctly specifying the parameters?  It sounds like the parameters are not being inserted properly into your final SQL that gets executed

Comment: That isn't SQL. It's Java code (I'm guessing) with some SQL with `?` placeholders in a string. My guess is you're trying to run it via `Statement#execute`. Instead, you want to use it with `PreparedStatement` and use the various `setXyz` methods on `PreparedStatement` to specify the values for the placeholders. Search for a Java JDBC tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

i need to use an @ symbol :/

@studentID,@studentFirstName..